# How to call a async function on "onSubmitted" in TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have the following async function:

```
Future<void> _fillstock(String text) async {
  stock = await fromtext(text);
  final Map<String, dynamic> data= (await stock?.get_data())!;
  double? change = data['change'];
  setState(() {
    nChange = change;
  });
}
```

And I have the build function:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Alert"),
    ),
    body: Column(children: [
      TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "name"),
          onSubmitted: (String text) {await _fillstock(text);}),
      Text("$nChange")
    ]));
  }
```

It gives an error in the "onSubmitted" line, because I can't call await there. How can I do it? How can I just run the async function that fills the nChange variable?

I tried with FutureBuilder, but with no success:

```
FutureBuilder<void>(
  future: _fillstock(text),
  builder: (snap, context) {
    return snap.widget;
  },
);
```

Comment: What if you add `async` ? `onSubmitted: (String text) async {...}`

Comment: Why do you need to wait for the fill function on onSubmitted? This can be a problem since you will pause the call on the widget, the best way would be to use a function of type void. Ex: `void _fillstock(String text) async {...}`

Comment: @Chance I need to grab some data from a get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a synchronised call from `onSubmitted`, it should be called with `async` or called without `await`.

```
      TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "name"),
          onSubmitted: (String text) async {await _fillstock(text);})
```

Or

```
      TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "name"),
          onSubmitted: _fillstock)
```

In both cases, `_fillstock` will be called asynchronously, and this will work.

Comment: I also had a problem with the emulator. Eventually, solved everything. Thank you.